# which version of bootstrap ie simple minimized version or sass powerd version of bootstrap is better for using in rails application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

i am developing an rails application and wanted to use simpleform gem and bootstrap,i have installed the required gems , but i am confused about which version to use ie minimized version or sass powered version , i would also like to know where to put both of these versions in vendor/assets or application/assets

this is my gem file

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.5' 
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'mysql2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:           
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          
group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'cancan'


gem 'simple_form'

group :assets do
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end
```

Comment: You probably want to use     gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

Comment: @JoelL but it's right at the bottom of this gemfile. `bootstrap-sass` might be a better option though. The curious thing is, they're **both** there. I wonder how did that come out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your problems are solved by Rails' asset pipeline.

`bootstrap-sass` essentially makes Bootstrap available for import in your `*.sass`/`*.scss` files, as well as `*.js` for JS components. How to use it is nicely described in [the gem's README on Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). You don't need to download any of the Bootstrap's files if you are using this gem, since it's exactly what it is responsible for.

**Sass-powered version is better for Rails** (in most cases) than a precompiled one since it's **more flexible**. It can be minimized and modified through Sass, and mixins from Bootstrap are available for use in your own styles to maintain a more unified look.

Stick to `bootstrap-sass` and `sass-rails` and remove `twitter-bootstrap-rails`. Why? Because  the same flexibility with this gem is achieved through the use of **LESS**, which would require setting it up first (extra gem `less-rails`).

Generally, Sass is more suitable for Ruby-based projects, LESS for JS-based. However, it's often possible to go against this without much effort, but it requires a bit of experience with your asset generation system. Keep it easier for yourself to develop.